# How to receive e-mails in a silverlight application?

Tags: c#, silverlight, web-services, email

I'm wondering whether anyone can help me with how to set up mailboxes for my silverlight application users.

Sending e-mails was simple enough, but now it seems to get tricky.

How do I implement an IMAP or POP3 service?
I've followed a couple of questions here on SO, but the answer is still eluding me...

Can anyone maybe send me a in general direction?
Any useful answers would be very much appreciated.

Comment: I've tried a range of solutions on this problem, and have to admit, "lesnikowski" is the best solution I've found, although it is not free, but it works wonderfully.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [MailSystem.Net](http://mailsystem.codeplex.com/license) (LGPL). It provides full support for SMTP, POP3, IMAP4, NNTP, MIME, S/MIME, OpenPGP, DNS, vCard, vCalendar, Anti-Spam (Bayesian , RBL, DomainKeys), Queueing, Mail Merge and WhoIs.

Answer (score 0):

Never tried this but heard of it one time:
http://www.emailyak.com/